# Inherit Gitlab predefined variables

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, predefined-variables

I have a Gitlab CI as below. My purpose: When build stage fail, notify stage will be trigger and send email to recipients

```
build website:
  stage: build
  script: ...

send email:
  stage: notify
  when: on_failure
  script: #send email to recipients
```

But in my content email, I want to use some predefined variables to refer to failure job. example: "Job $CI_JOB_NAME in stage $CI_JOB_STAGE pipelines failure". How can I refer variables to stage build from stage notify. Please help me, bro. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GitLab jobs are independent. If you want to share some context between jobs - you can use artifacts

```
build website:
  stage: build
  script:
    - # build website
    - # save whatever you want in log.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./log.txt

send email:
  stage: notify
  when: on_failure
  script: 
    - export CI_JOB_NAME = $(cat log.txt)
    - #send email to recipients
```